# Порядок освоения ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Хочу осовить эту технологию. Подскажите, в каком порядке изучать главы учебников. Я думаю, что начать надо с мастер-страниц и аякса.

Comment: искренний вам совет: выкиньте из головы ASP.NET.Это не лучший выбор. У того же MS есть куда более адекватная и перспективная технология ASP.NET MVC. WebForms в силу разных причин - не лучший выбор

Comment: Я MVC уже подучил немного. Но есть интерес узнать, как всё было до.

Comment: "До" было много чего, в том числе и обычный ASP (без .NET), однако особого смысла в их изучении немного

Comment: Какие Вы видите существенные преимущества MVC перед WebForms?

Comment: @Alex9, все эти споры относительно крутости той или иной технологии похожи как две капли воды на холивары C# vs Java и т.п. Раз и навсегда запомните, в любой ситуации нужно исходить из контекста. Т.е. отталкиваться от той задачи, и тех бизнес требований, которые стоят перед Вами, как перед разработчиком. Если в одной ситуации использование MVC более оправдано, чем WebForms это еще не значит, что не существует такой ситуации когда все в корне поменяется наоборот. Если говорить о контексте использования, то можно сказать следующее MVC - предпочтительнее для Интернета, WebForms - Интранета!

Comment: >Какие Вы видите существенные преимущества MVC перед WebForms?

это довольно обширная тема, я не думаю, что формат этого вопроса подходит для подобного обсуждения. 

>MVC - предпочтительнее для Интернета, WebForms - Интранета!

@sp7 вас не затруднит аргументировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, нужно начать по порядку.

1. Уверенное знание C#, как самого языка, так и его возможностей, касающихся работы с БД (здесь либо Entity Framework, либо ADO.NET), XML, текстовыми файлами, LINQ и т.д.
2. Понимание того, как работает WEB, хотя для ASP.NET WebForms это не сильно критично, но все же знать не помешает, т.к. различия есть.
3. HTML, CSS, JavaScript базовый уровень - чтобы хватило знаний подправить и по верстке или что-то свое написать, если где-то из коробки работает не так, как хотелось бы.
4. Хорошая книга [**«ASP.NET 4.5 с примерами на C# 5.0 для профессионалов»**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785845918789&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0). Рекомендую эту. Уважаемый автор, пишет и объясняет хорошо.
5. Терпение.

Пожалуй для начала, этого будет достаточно.